# JavaScript and Composition

Tags: javascript, oop, composition

I am currently trying to understand compositions to be able to implement them into a piece of code I am working on. I don't see the importance/use of compositions atm, but for my purposes it seems that I have to use it.

I don't have any examples to guide myself at the moment. I already tried looking on Google and YouTube.

What I am trying to accomplish with compositions can be seen below:

The system is intended to allow booking multiple seats for a plane flight. We want to use two classes to implement this system, a Flight class and an Aircraft class. Every Flight object should contain an instance of an Aircraft object. The roles and attributes of these classes are:

**Aircraft:** This class will store two attributes, an aircraft name as a string and a numeric maximum capacity.

**Flight:** This class will store information necessary for booking seats. It will store the **flight number** (as a string), a **number of seats reserved**, and it will contain an **Aircraft object** that will be used to determine **the maximum number of seats** that can be booked. This class must code a bookSeats(noSeats) member function which will be used to book seats. In bookSeats(noSeats) you are expected to throw an exception if there are not enough seats left on the plane to allow for the booking.

After you have defined your two classes, instantiate one or more Flights and attempt to book seats such that the booking would be successful, and the booking would throw an exception.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test Template</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function Flight(flightNo, maxSeats, reservedSeats ){
         this.no = "AC781";
         //Aaircarft object is needeed to get max number of seats
         //this.maxSeats = 522; 
         this.reserved = 90;
         }

         //
         function Aircraft (planeName,maxSeats){
         this.planeName = "test"
         this.maxSeats = 522;
         }

         Flight.prototype.bookSeats = function(noSeats){
         if( noSeats + this.reserved <= this.maxSeats ){
         this.reserved+= noSeats
         } else {
         throw "Not enough seats";  // THROW EXCEPTION
         }
         }


         //Test the Flight implementation
         var toHalifax = new Flight();
         alert("Before update " + "No:" + toHalifax.no + 
             " Max seats:" + toHalifax.maxSeats +
             " Reserved:"   + toHalifax.reserved );
         try{      
          toHalifax.bookSeats(46);
          alert("After update " + "No:" + toHalifax.no + 
             " Max seats:" + toHalifax.maxSeats +
             " Reserved:"   + toHalifax.reserved );
         } catch ( err ){
          alert( err );
         }


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Comment: I read that over a few times, can't figure out what your question is....

Comment: I want to know how to create an Aircraft object that will be used to determine the the maximum number of seats that can be booked in the flight class. I believe that this can only be achieved by using compositions(?)

Answer (score 1):

The `Aircraft` object should be a parameter for the "constructor-like function" of the `Flight` object.

**Disclaimer**

I assume that you are using flights/aircraft as an example for a coding exercise, and that you are not building a real-world airline reservation system. If you were building a real-world airline reservation system, I would give a different answer.